# How to create horizontal line in html report table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, report

I want to make a report that can be print

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWBFe.png)

but the table below is not closed because the sentence is still continue on the second page, how do I add a horizontal line so that the table can be closed even though the sentence is still continue to the next page

i already add this syntax in @media print
`.page-break {page-break-after: always;}`
but still not work

can someone help me

Comment: you can add the border line on top and the bottom for each row, then `border-collapse: collapse;` will make it to look like only one, when the top and bottom border line touch each other, and then when page break split the rows, you still have the line there because bottom is not collapsed anymore

Comment: Have you tried `break-inside: avoid;` or something to prevent the page from breaking inside a row?